# Mule Logging - How to write a log that be browse in web browser?

Tags: mule

In my mule flow, I'm trying to build a log that can be viewed in web browser. Put another way, it's similar to writing a log file in html. Any recommendations for doing this with Mule? Also what are some of the mule components required to perform this?

At the end of the day it should look pretty similar to this (refer to image attached), of course it's with a different log content.
[image: Write a log file using Mule in html]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mule uses log4j for logging and you can configure that to output HTML. See Mule docs for [logging](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Configuring+Logging) and [Logger](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Logger+Component+Reference) for more info and follow the links there to log4j to learn more advanced configuration options. For a quick start you can also see [this example](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/08/how-to-create-logs-in-html-format-using-log4j/) for a simple log4j.properties file that writes the log into an HTML file. In Mule Studio, put that log4j.properties file in your app's src/main/resources folder and you will get an application.html log file in your app root folder when you run the app.

Comment: thanks. http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Logging+With+Mule+ESB+3.x mentions that it works only in Mule standalone. Does this mean that using it to log will not work with MuleStudio?

Comment: My above comment refers to configuring the logger in Mule Studio.